# make file target to check for installed dependencies

Tags: python, makefile

I have a makefile where I have targets that depend on having some external clients installed (python3, libxml2, etc).

Here is my makefile

```
.PHONY: test install-packages mac-setup checkenv target help

EXTERNALS = python3 pip3 xmllint pytest pipenv
P := $(foreach exec,$(EXTERNALS),$(if $(shell which $(exec)),missing,$(warning "===>>>WARNING:  No required `$(exec)` in PATH, run `make mac-setup` + `make install-packages` <<<===")))

test: ## run all tests in test directory
    pipenv run pytest -v --ignore=path payload_files .

install-packages: ##install python packages listed in Pipfile
    pipenv install

mac-setup: ## setup mac for testing
    brew install libxml2
    brew install python3
    brew install pipenv


# see https://github.mycompany.com/ea/ea_test_player_unified/blob/master/run-feature.sh

help:
    @grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sort | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'

.DEFAULT_GOAL := help
```

Notice the line

```
P := $(foreach exec,$(EXTERNALS),$(if $(shell which $(exec)),missing,$(warning "===>>>WARNING:  No required `$(exec)` in PATH, run `make mac-setup` + `make install-packages` <<<===")))
```

This checks for the binaries required.  This works.... however I would rather have a `checkenv` target that performs this and errors so I can attach it too specific targets like `test` instead of printing out a WARNING that might be overlooked.

Want:

```
checkenv:  # error if which ${binary} fails or *even better* if if binary --version doesn't return the right version:  python3 pip3 xmllint pytest pipenv
```

I tried various techniques that I found around the web including stackoverflow.... but most use the technique I am using above that don't use a make target or just check for one binary.  I tried building a loop through an array of binaries but just couldn't get the syntax correct due to make being a PITA :)

Any suggestions?

Note I'm a python newbie, task is to rewrite some jmeter tests in python....so if you have any thoughts on the above approach feel free to share.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: As long as you're committed to GNU `make` anyway, you could consider using its `$(eval)` function.  You should be able to combine that with looping to dynamically generate *bona fide* rules.  I'm afraid at the moment I'm not up for working out all the details, however.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see what the problem is. It looks very straightforward to me, as make allows using multiple targets on the same line:

```
EXTERNALS := python3 pip3 xmllint pytest pipenv
python3_version := Python 3.7.3
pip3_version := ...
...

.PHONY: checkenv $(EXTERNALS)
checkenv: $(EXTERNALS)
$(EXTERNALS):
    if [ "`$@ --version`" != "$($@_version)" ]; then echo "$@ check failed"; false; fi
```